Trouble matching data - python pie chart
Colleagues,
I am aiming to create a pie chart linked with the following dict:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


dict_data = {1: 873, 2: 654, 0: 451, 3: 218}


plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.set_palette("muted", 8)
plt.pie(data=dict_data.values(), x=dict_data.keys(), labels=dict_data.keys(), autopct='%.0f%%', startangle = 90)
plt.legend(title = "Education Level")

plt.show()


Why are keys (labels) and values (figures) on the chart mixed with each other and not shown respectively that is 0-451, 1-873 etc?
Why there is nothing for "0" label?

I think you just want
plt.pie(x=dict_data.values(), labels=dict_data.keys(), autopct='%.0f%%', startangle = 90)


The data keyword is for when you are passing something like a pandas data frame.  Then data would be the data frame and x would be a string to chose the column from that data frame.
